# Confusion In Derivative of Electrostatic Potential Energy Of 2 Charge System

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy, conventions, coulombs-law

[image]

In my textbook, the derivative shows a -ve sign in front of the integral.
My confusion is why is that -ve sign there?
Isn't the direction of external force and displacement the same and hence shouldn't the dot product be +ve?

Comment: Since $dx$ is negative per the problem statement, $-dx$ is positive making the work done by the external force F positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is truly confusing.  If you are working along the positive side of a chosen x axis, the x component of the external force is negative.  The dot product of this with a positive dx is negative.  In general, if  integrating outward, the integral of dx/$x^2$ = - 1/x. With a negative dot product, this becomes + 1/x. But 1/x gets smaller as x gets bigger, so when evaluated at the limits the result is negative. If on the other hand, you are integrating inward (as indicated by the limits), the result is positive.  Bottom line, the external force does positive work when coming in from infinity.

Comment: Thanks so much that cleared it up!